# Toggling the CD (RLSD) signal line on a serial port in Windows C

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, signals

I am trying to set the Carrier Detect (Receive Line Signal Detect) pin on a serial port being controlled by my Windows application. I am already able to set the RTS line high using this function:

```
EscapeCommFunction(handle, SETRTS);
```

and then subsequently clear it by using:

```
EscapeCommFunction(handle, CLRRTS);
```

I want to be able to do this exact same thing with the CD line, but no such SET/CLR flags exist for the EscapeCommFunction.

Comment: I think the CD pin is an *input*, not an *output*.

Comment: I know it is usually used for detection, but I am using it in a non conventional way for both input and output.

Comment: PC hardware may not be capable of using it as an output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PC serial port was designed from the viewpoint of a terminal, not a modem. The CD signal is an output from a modem and an input to a terminal. Even if the port hardware allows you to change the direction (of which I'm skeptical) the standard interface would not be programmed that way.

Answer (score 0):

RS232 devices can be either a DTE (Data Terminal Equipment) or DCE (Data Communications Equipment).  Examples of DCEs are modems, multiplexors and some line drivers (technically a modem), everything else including your computer is a DTE.

The DCD (RLSD) is an output from a DCE to indicate that has detected the carrier on the comms link i.e. can see the remote modem.

I know of no way to convert a DTE into a DCE with a standard serial port.